# ¿Como llenar un listView usando web service desde un ViewModel en Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Tengo el siguiente código en donde lleno un listview usando un webservice.

En el code behind:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using Xamarin_WS_ListView.Model;

namespace Xamarin_WS_ListView.View
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class JsonParsingPage : ContentPage
    {
        public JsonParsingPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        //BindingContext = new ListaDatosViewModel(); deseo obtener los datos desde un viewmodel
        }
        public async void GetJSON()
        {   

            //Check network status 
            if (NetworkCheck.IsInternet())
            {

                var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
                var response = await client.GetAsync("http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/");
                string contactsJson = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                ContactList ObjContactList = new ContactList();
                if (contactsJson != "")
                {
                    //Converting JSON Array Objects into generic list
                    ObjContactList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContactList>(contactsJson);
                }
                //Binding listview with server response  
                listviewConacts.ItemsSource = ObjContactList.contacts;
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("JSONParsing", "No network is available.", "Ok");
            }
            //Hide loader after server response  
            ProgressLoader.IsVisible = false;
        }

        private void listviewContacts_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var itemSelectedData = e.SelectedItem as Contact;
            Navigation.PushAsync(new JsonDetailsPage(itemSelectedData));
        }
    }
}
```

En la vista:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Xamarin_WS_ListView.View.JsonParsingPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Grid>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Margin="10" Text="JSON Parsing" FontSize="25" />
                    <ListView x:Name="listviewConacts" Grid.Row="1"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemSelected="listviewContacts_ItemSelected">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="10">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding name}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Grid.Row="0" TextColor="Blue"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding email}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Grid.Row="1" TextColor="Orange"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding phone.mobile}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Grid.Row="2" TextColor="Gray"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>

                                        <BoxView HeightRequest="2" Margin="0,10,10,0" BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </ViewCell>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </Grid>
                <ActivityIndicator x:Name="ProgressLoader" IsRunning="True"/>
            </Grid>

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

De esta forma me funciona. Pero lo que deseo, es llenar el listview usando un viewmodel, es decir, en el code behind se llena en el BindingContex en el constuctor con el ViewModel, y en la vista  se llenado en el listView ItemsSource="{Binding  Contactos}".

No se si me explique bien, pero el objetivo, es que cumpla con el MVVM, en donde desde el viewmodel se encargue de llenar el ListView de la vista.
Si alguien tiene algún ejemplo o idea, se le agradecería mucho.
Saludos

Answer (score 2):

A tu list view necesitas agregarle la propiedad ItemSource y hacer la propiedad bindeable como en el siguiente ejemplo

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfItems}" ...>
    ...
    </ListView>
```

Y en tu view model, creas una propiedad de tipo List

```
private List<ObjContactList> _listOfItems;
public List <ObjContactList> ListOfItems {
    get { return _listOfItems ?? _listOfItems == new List<ObjContactList>; }
    set {
        if(_listOfItems != value) {
            _listOfItems = value;
            SetPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

en donde la propiedad debe tener el mismo nombre que la propiedad bindeable que declaraste en el XAML, entonces ahí le seteas la lista a la propiedad

Comment: tambien debes indicar cual es  tu Binding Context, ya sea en el xaml o en el contructor de tu code Behind